# Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I am new to MongoDB. I have worked on Legacy Mainframe and DB2.
I have created a Pipeline through Aggregation Builder in MongoDB Compass. I need to export the result set of my Aggregation Query in a 'json' file. The result should be download the same way we download the 'Filter' result set in a 'json' file using the 'Export Collection' button.
For that, I though of creating a 'View' of my Pipeline and Export the 'View'. But as soon as I open the 'View' in Compass, it throws an error "Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in". Please help.

Comment: You need to pass `{allowDiskUse : true }` as an option. Refer to this
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/allowdiskuse-setting-in-compass/11851/4